# Preserve local time zone in serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a Django Rest Framework Serializer:

```
class LocalTZDateTimeField(serializers.DateTimeField):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        local_timezone = pytz.timezone(getattr(settings, 'LOCAL_TIMEZONE', None))
        kwargs['default_timezone'] = local_timezone
        super(LocalTZDateTimeField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

which displays dates like this:

`"create_dt": "2016-01-04T09:06:17.344952-05:00" # Eastern time, as desired`

I don't want to show the fractional seconds, so the docs suggest specify a datetime format, which I did:

```
'DATETIME_FORMAT': "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%Z%z",
```

which *mostly* works, except now the dates are converted to UTC.
`"create_dt": "2016-01-04T14:06:17UTC+0000",`

I can't find anything that will allow me to show them in Eastern.  (open to a better solution to supressing the fractional seconds, if I'm off the mark)

Edit:

To clarify, the goal is to keep the current timestamp in Eastern, as it is now, but without the fractional seconds being shown:

`"2016-01-04T09:06:17-05:00"`

I'm investigating the `to_representation` method:

```
def to_representation(self, instance):
    representation = super(LocalTZDateTimeField, self).to_representation(instance)
    return representation
```

Setting a pdb in the middle of that confirms that even without setting the datetime format in settings, `representation` is what I want--no fractional seconds, correct time zone.  However, what gets displayed is still incorrect:  with fractional settings if I don't include the datetime format; wrong time zone if I do.  Not sure where that's getting set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `to representation` method was the way to go!

```
def to_representation(self, instance):
    format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%Z%z"
    local_timezone = pytz.timezone(getattr(settings, 'America/New_York', None))
    representation = instance.astimezone(local_timezone).strftime(format)
    return representation
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, [this link](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#date-and-time-fields) for you will be useful. Quote from Django Rest Framework documentation:

```
signature: DateTimeField(format=api_settings.DATETIME_FORMAT,
 input_formats=None)
```

> **format** - A string representing the output format. If not specified,
>   this defaults to the same value as the **DATETIME_FORMAT** settings key,
>   which will be 'iso-8601' unless set. Setting to a format string
>   indicates that to_representation return values should be coerced to
>   string output. Format strings are described below. Setting this value
>   to None indicates that Python datetime objects should be returned by
>   to_representation. In this case the datetime encoding will be
>   determined by the renderer.

And usefull part about input formats:

> **input_formats** - A list of strings
>   representing the input formats which may be used to parse the date. If
>   not specified, the **DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS** setting will be used, which
>   defaults to ['iso-8601'].

Answer (score 0):

this works for me:

```
from django.utils import timezone

def to_representation(self, instance):
    representation = instance.astimezone(timezone.get_default_timezone()).isoformat()
    return representation
```